# Group fields of the same field value that are next to one another

Tags: python, django

I have activity stream on my application and I would like to display only one field activities of the same type in row. For example when user add 3 comments, then add article, and next 3 comments I would like to have in activity stream 3 entries. But I must store in database separate fields for each activity to have more precise activity on demand.

```
class ActivityStream(models.Model):

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In other words I have some activities on `ActivityStream`, each one have type and creation date set. I need to query it (sorted by creation date), but with grouped activities that have the same type and only if there is no activities with other type between them.

Example data in database:

```
+----------------+---------------------+
|      type      |       created       |
+----------------+---------------------+
| comment        | 2014-05-21 22:33:39 |
| comment        | 2014-05-21 22:35:43 |
| article        | 2014-05-22 11:17:11 |
| article        | 2014-05-22 12:23:37 |
| comment        | 2014-05-22 12:27:11 |
| comment        | 2014-05-22 12:29:33 |
| comment        | 2014-05-22 12:37:01 |
| comment        | 2014-05-22 13:04:14 |
| article        | 2014-05-22 14:44:11 |
| comment        | 2014-05-23 17:51:17 |
| article_delete | 2014-05-23 17:55:17 |
| comment        | 2014-05-27 9:37:01  |
+----------------+---------------------+
```

What I want to get from queryset:

```
[
    {'type': u'comment',        'created': datetime(2014, 5, 21, 22, 35, 43), 'count': 2},
    {'type': u'article',        'created': datetime(2014, 5, 22, 12, 23, 37), 'count': 2},
    {'type': u'comment',        'created': datetime(2014, 5, 22, 13, 4, 14),  'count': 4},
    {'type': u'article',        'created': datetime(2014, 5, 22, 14, 44, 11), 'count': 1},
    {'type': u'comment',        'created': datetime(2014, 5, 23, 17, 51, 17), 'count': 1},
    {'type': u'article_delete', 'created': datetime(2014, 5, 23, 17, 55, 17), 'count': 1},
    {'type': u'comment',        'created': datetime(2014, 5, 27, 9, 37, 1),   'count': 1},
]
```

Is there any way to do it in django using queryset?

Comment: Can you post your models for ```Article``` and ```Comment```? I'm not quite sure I understand your problem exactly so maybe even some code of what you would want to do, or what you're doing now to get around this would be helpful too.

Comment: There is no need for giving `Article` and `Comment`, because activity stream won't use it. I will edit question and add activity stream model.

Comment: I've edited my question with `ActivityStream` model and some more explanation.

Comment: Okay, I still don't understand your question. Can you write out the results you want from the data?

Comment: Added some data in question. I hope now everything's clear :)

Comment: You can't do what you're looking to with Django's ```QuerySet```. You'll need to use ```raw``` or fetch the data and manipulate it in python.